# Boost not caching subdomains

Tags: caching

I have a website with subdomains set up, the naked domain without any subdomain gets cached by boost and there is the message by boost in the footer. But any subdomain does not get cached. We are using the sites module http://drupal.org/project/sites, to split the subdomains into different drupal sites.

We have this error  on the status  report page - Boost crawler did not get a 200 response; 302 returned instead.

my boost settings

```
  ### BOOST START ###
  AddDefaultCharset utf-8
  FileETag None
  <FilesMatch "(\.html)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header set Expires "Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT"
      Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
    </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>
  <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset utf-8 .html
    AddCharset utf-8 .css
    AddCharset utf-8 .js
  </IfModule>
  <FilesMatch "(\.html)$">
    ForceType text/html
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "(\.js)$">
    ForceType text/javascript
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "(\.css)$">
    ForceType text/css
  </FilesMatch>

  # NORMAL - Cached css & js files
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/perm/%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.css -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/perm/%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.css [L,QSA,T=text/css]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/perm/%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.js -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/perm/%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}_\.js [L,QSA,T=text/javascript]

  # Caching for anonymous users
  # Skip boost IF not get request OR uri has wrong dir OR cookie is set OR request came from this server OR https request
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|HEAD)$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^/(admin|cache|misc|modules|sites|system|openid|themes|node/add))|(/(comment/reply|edit|user|user/(login|password|register))$) [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} DRUPAL_UID [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Pragma} no-cache [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cache-Control} no-cache [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule .* - [S=1]

  # NORMAL
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/normal/%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html -s
  RewriteRule .* cache/normal/%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html [L,T=text/html]

  ### BOOST END ###
```

Answer (score 1):

I applied this patch and now it works

http://drupal.org/node/1508994